# How to get bus element information in Matlab programmatically?

Tags: matlab, simulink

Say there are Simulink buses in a model, Bus1  and Bus. How can we access the Bus1 info like which elements it has, their dimensions etc.

Comment: Virtual or Non-Virtual bus?

Comment: @scotty3785 Non-Virtual bus

Comment: I've linked to the appropriate page for getting information about non-virtual buses in my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You can query data about buses by looking at the Signal Hierarchy or Compiled Bus Type of a signal. 
However it appears that if you only have a virtual bus, you can only get the signal names and not the types/dimensions etc. The compiled bus type for a virtual bus is "VIRTUAL_BUS" so no information is provided.

This [page](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/view-composite-signals.html) discussed how to programmatically query a signal on a bus but as stated above, you will only find information, if you have a non-virtual bus.